# Min function in sql server is not working properly giving 0

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, max, min

i want to substract the todays max value form the todays min value . im getting the max value properly but min value getting as 0. how to substract todays min value from max value of kvarh.

Data type kvarh - float, devicetimestamp - datetime

code

```
   select(
  SELECT MAX(kvarh)
  FROM [Transformer].[dbo].[Total_Power]
 WHERe DeviceTimeStamp < GETDATE()
 and DEVICEIMEI = '868996')
 -
  (SELECT MIN(kvarh)
  FROM [Transformer].[dbo].[Total_Power]
 WHERe DeviceTimeStamp < GETDATE()
 and DEVICEIMEI = '868996')
  as Difference
```

sample data

```
     A_id   DeviceImei  DeviceTimeStamp           KWH       KVARH       
    985302  868996     2020-10-16 10:30:30.000  36682.5     424107.1    
    985298  868996     2020-10-16 10:15:31.000  36678.94    424103.3    
    985296  8689960    2020-10-16 10:00:29.000  36675.88    424099.8
```

Comment: there was date conversion issue. there was no 0 values.plz check my answer i have posted. getting proper values but is it code good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have check your query and it is working fine. You can reduce it a little bit like this:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [A_id] INT  
   ,[DeviceImei]  INT
   ,[DeviceTimeStamp] DATETIME
   ,[KWH] DECIMAL(9,2)
   ,[KVARH] DECIMAL(9,2)
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([A_id], [DeviceImei], [DeviceTimeStamp], [KWH], [KVARH])
VALUES (985302, 868996, '2020-10-16 00:30:30.000', 36682.5, 424107.1)
      ,(985298, 868996, '2020-10-16 00:15:31.000', 36678.94, 424103.3)
      ,(985296, 8689960, '2020-10-16 00:00:29.000', 36675.88, 424099.8);


SELECT MAX(kvarh) - MIN(kvarh) AS Difference
FROM @DataSource
WHERE DeviceTimeStamp < GETDATE()
   and DEVICEIMEI = '868996';
```

The `MIN` function will not return `0` with this sample data - if no rows are found you will get `NULL` as a result. You will get `0` only when there is only one row matching your condition, because you will substract the same value.

For example:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [A_id] INT  
   ,[DeviceImei]  INT
   ,[DeviceTimeStamp] DATETIME
   ,[KWH] DECIMAL(9,2)
   ,[KVARH] DECIMAL(9,2)
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([A_id], [DeviceImei], [DeviceTimeStamp], [KWH], [KVARH])
VALUES (985302, 868996, '2020-10-16 00:30:30.000', 36682.5, 424107.1)
      --,(985298, 868996, '2020-10-16 00:15:31.000', 36678.94, 424103.3)
      ,(985296, 8689960, '2020-10-16 00:00:29.000', 36675.88, 424099.8);


SELECT MAX(kvarh) - MIN(kvarh) AS Difference
FROM @DataSource
WHERE DeviceTimeStamp < GETDATE()
   and DEVICEIMEI = '868996';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select(
select max(KVARH) from [Transformer].[dbo].[Total_Power] 
where cast(DeviceTimeStamp as Date)  = cast(getdate() as Date) and DEVICEIMEI = '868996'
)
-
(
select min(KVARH) from [Transformer].[dbo].[Total_Power] 
where cast(DeviceTimeStamp as Date)  = cast(getdate() as Date) and DEVICEIMEI = '868996'
)
as Todays_Consumption
```

Answer (score 0):

QuYour min subquery could have 0 >>WHERe DeviceTimeStamp < GETDATE()

```
   select(
  SELECT MAX(kvarh)
  FROM [Transformer].[dbo].[Total_Power]
  WHERe DeviceTimeStamp < GETDATE()
  and DEVICEIMEI = '868996')
  -
   (SELECT MIN(kvarh)  /*could have 0 value*/
   FROM [Transformer].[dbo].[Total_Power]
   WHERe DeviceTimeStamp < GETDATE()
   and DEVICEIMEI = '868996'
   and kvarh >0)/*try adding this*/
   as Difference
```